# Python AudioPlayer on Chromebook fails to play file

Tags: python, chromebook

I have this python program:

```
from gtts import gTTS
from audioplayer import AudioPlayer

speech = gTTS('Hello, world!')
speech.save('test.mp3')
AudioPlayer('test.mp3').play(block=True)
```

This runs fine on my Macbook. When I try to run it on my chromebook I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    AudioPlayer('test.mp3').play(block=True)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioplayer/abstractaudioplayer.py", line 114, in play
    self._doplay(loop, block)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/audioplayer/audioplayer_linux.py", line 45, in _doplay
    raise AudioPlayerError(
audioplayer.abstractaudioplayer.AudioPlayerError: Failed to play "/home/me/test.mp3"
```

The AudioPlayer pypi page (https://pypi.org/project/audioplayer/) lists packages to install. The very first one I try, python-gst-1.0 isn't found.

```
sudo apt-get install python-gst-1.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gst-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python-gst-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python-gst-1.0'
```

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: python-gst-1.0 is here.
[Package: python-gst-1.0 (1.14.0-1)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/amd64/python-gst-1.0)
You can also use packages other than AudioPlayer that can play mp3.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up installing mpg123 and shelling out to it from python to play my mp3. Not sure if I should just close this question, or answer it. I didn't actually go down the route of installing pythong-gst-1.0 from your link.